# Can we write "fractional root" symbol in math?

Tags: roots, exponentiation, fractions

Fractional exponents are legit but I have never seen fractional roots, so I just wonder if we can write fractional roots such as this:

[image]

It sometimes can be convenient to think about too.

Comment: That's quite understandable, but little benefit compared to $x=c^{b/a}$.

Comment: Is your question answered or do you want something else?

Comment: I would say it's asking for trouble. $x^{a/b} = \sqrt[b/a]{x}$, and people _will_ forget to invert that fraction.

Comment: Thanks guys! Today I find Ilaya's suggestion more convenient too, i.e. $$x^{\frac{a}{b}}=C \to x=C^{\frac{b}{a}}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do have fractional roots but, I write it like -
$$x^{\frac{a}{b}}=C \to x=C^{\frac{b}{a}}$$
But anyways there are a lot of ways you can represent math symbols and I can't find anything wrong in your representation too.

Answer (score 0):

Of course we can.

to find the one-half root of a number $y$ is equivalent to solving for $x$ in this equation.

$$x^{\frac{1}{2}}=y$$

Then

$$x=\sqrt[\frac{1}{2}]y$$

More generally, if $y=\sqrt[\frac{a}{b}]x$ for integers $a$ and $b$, then $x^{\frac{b}{a}}=y$

Because irrational numbers can be arbitrarily approximated by rational numbers, the $n$th root is well-defined for all arbitrary nonzero real $n$.

And through application of Euler's identity $e^{iπ}+1=0$, when $e$ is the base of the natural logarithm and $i^2=-1$, then we can well-define $nth$ roots for all arbitrary nonzero complex numbers $n$.